# T-SQL JOIN table on condition

Tags: t-sql, join

I have a procedure with select from 4 tables. In dependence on input variable, I want to join and show 2 or all 4. So if the @var = 1 only table1 and table2 will be output, if @var = 2 join from all 4 tables is output.
What I have tried is this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM t1  
JOIN t2 ON t1.pk1 = t2.pk1
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.pk2 = t3.pk2 AND CASE @var = 2 THEN 1 ELSE = 0 END = 1
LEFT JOIN t4 ON t3.pk3 = t4.pk3 AND CASE @var = 2 THEN 1 ELSE = 0 END = 1
```

But the output is shown only for variable = 2 otherwise the output is empty.

In reality I have a lot more tables connected together and these 2 are needed only for WHERE part (more filtering). When I don't get any columns to filter from t3 and t4 I want to show everything without any connection with these tables. When I have data to filter from t3 and t4 I need to join them and use them in WHERE clause.

**EDIT:**
So the final solution is like this:

```sql
IF (@var = 2)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM t1  
    JOIN t2 ON t1.pk1 = t2.pk1
    LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.pk2 = t3.pk2
    LEFT JOIN t4 ON t3.pk3 = t4.pk3
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM t1  
    JOIN t2 ON t1.pk1 = t2.pk1
END
```

Comment: Why don't you just simply use `IF statement` and put specific query? Also check out `JOINS`, you are doing `INNER JOIN`, which means if you send @var = 2 you will never get anything from that query, you should be using `LEFT JOIN` if you really want to go that way ...

Comment: Well, that is solution, i wasn't open minded enough :) now I have two very long SELECTs divided by small if.

Comment: Have you tried putting `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN` on t3 and t4?

Comment: Yeah, I had them in notes but forget them to add. Already Edited

Comment: @Error404, your *final solution* is fine (and might be best choice!), but it is *procedural* and therefore of no usage in VIEWs or iTVFs - quite a draw-back...

Comment: True, but that was never an goal.  I know it will always be only procedure and it will be always called only by program (with some additional back end). In addition the rest of code is not mine and I can not rework it from the pieces as it needs.

Comment: One last hint (just to keep in mind): The solution with `IF` will return a different result set, than the solution with a condition on `ON`, at least if called with `SELECT *` as above. In general it is a good idea to call the columns by name anyway ;-)... On the consumer side it is - in most cases easier to deal with a fixed structure...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

Let's create a *mockup scenario* to simulate your issue:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
DECLARE @t2 TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,t1ID INT /*FK to t1*/,SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
DECLARE @t3 TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,t2ID INT /*FK to t2*/,SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
DECLARE @t4 TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,t3ID INT /*FK to t3*/,SomeValue VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES('Row 1'),('Row 2');
INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES(1,'Row 1.1'),(1,'Row 1.2'),(2,'Row 2.1');
INSERT INTO @t3 VALUES(1,'Row 1.1.1'),(1,'Row 1.1.2'),(2,'Row 1.2.1'),(3,'Row 2.1.1');
INSERT INTO @t4 VALUES(1,'Row 1.1.1.1'),(1,'Row 1.1.1.2'),(4,'Row 2.1.1.1'),(4,'Row 2.1.1.2');
```

--Now we need your variable `@var`

```
DECLARE @var INT;
```

--We can set this to either 1 or 2 (or leave it unset, which is `NULL`)

```
--SET @var=1; --show all
SET @var=2; --just t1 and t2
```

--Check the query's result with various input:

```
SELECT * 
FROM @t1 t1  
INNER JOIN @t2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.t1ID
LEFT JOIN @t3 t3 ON t2.ID = t3.t2ID AND ISNULL(@var,1)=1
LEFT JOIN @t4 t4 ON t3.ID = t4.t3ID AND ISNULL(@var,1)=1;
```

The idea in short:

The `ON`-clause will return `FALSE` due to the `AND` in any case, where `@var` is neiter `NULL` nor `1`.
Both values `1` and `NULL` will be taken as `1`. Any other value will not be equal to `1`.

But I'm not fully sure, if I really got what you need...